# PHP Twitter API (Abraham's) - Could not authenticate issue

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am having some problems with implementing the twitter api. I am using [Abraham's method](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to connect to Twitter but I get this error:

```
object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(27) "Could not authenticate you."
  ["request"]=>
  string(302) "/1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=79CrBl2oYlaATF7YOn0New&oauth_nonce=014df8945398b9605b78703829f93c45&oauth_signature=7OnRBeraaGxXgLbTNQ3%2BFdMAIPs%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1314776180&oauth_token=U7iPIyqv7IJyq1VkvKsf06KE6KQOtVDPBEwwqRjhg&oauth_version=1.0"
}
```

This is my code:

```
$to = new TwitterOAuth();
        $tok = $to->getRequestToken(CURRURL);
        $request_link = $to->getAuthorizeURL($tok);
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token']= $tok['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] = $tok['oauth_token_secret'];

if ((!isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) || ($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])=='') {

            $to = new TwitterOAuth($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret']);
            $token_credentials = $to->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
            $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] =$token_credentials['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] = $token_credentials['oauth_token_secret'];
        } else {
            $connection = new TwitterOAuth($access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
            $user_info = $to->get('account/verify_credentials');

            //die(var_dump($user_info));

            $data = array(
            "twitter" => array(
                "oauth_provider" => "twitter",
                "oauth_uid" => $user_info->id,
                "first_name" => $user_info->name,
                "last_name" => "",
                "username" => $user_info->screen_name,
                "email" => "",
                "gender" => "",
                "hometown" => "",
                "location" => $user_info->location
                )
            );

            array_push($social,$data);

        }
```

I have been banging my head to the wall over this, so any suggestions would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when you initialize your method `TwitteroAuth` you've to pass also your consumer_key and consumer_secret that Twitter gives you.

Second, after the `getAuthorizeURL` you've to redirect the user to the Twitter website to allow them to accept you access to their information.

After the user allows Twitter to use its own information, Twitter redirects the user to your callback page. In your example is what contains the constant `CURRURL`.

You'll receive two new information with your URL the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` and you gonna initialize TwitterOAuth again with this, the consumer_key, consumer_secret, and theses two new parameters. `TwitterOAuth(key, secret, token, token_secret)`

And only after it you'll be able to get the user information with `$user_info = $to->get('account/verify_credentials');`

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem with the same error message (`Could not authenticate you.`) when reusing same oauth credentials across different applications (or even in different environments for the same application).

AFAIK Twitter is very susceptible about this, try to register a new application in your twitter account to see if this is the problem.

Comment: I created a new app with my twitter account and used that consumer key and secret to test the code, but it gave me the save error..